# CPL_write_ogr error when writing out shape file in R

Tags: r, r-sf

I've used this script multiple times already and it worked fine until now. I'm currently getting an error when I try writing out the shape files. Can anyone give me some insight on what this error means? The shape file in my input seems to be a normal shape file. Also, nowhere in my code am I trying to create an Object field.

Here's the error I am receiving:

```
Writing layer MonroeMD14F0037_1' to data source N:\MonroeMD14F0037_1.shp' using driver ESRI Shapefile Creating field ÃƒÆ’_OBJECT failed.Error in CPL_write_ogr(obj, dsn, layer, driver, as.character(dataset_options),  : 


Layer creation failed.In addition: Warning message:In CPL_write_ogr(obj, dsn, layer, driver, as.character(dataset_options),  :GDAL Error 1: Failed to create field name 'ÃƒÆ’_OBJECT': cannot convert to ISO-8859-1
```

Comment: can you post a sample of your data using `dput(head(deermig.sp,10))`? That might help someone to reproduce your error

Comment: This seems to indicate that MonroeMD14F0037_1 has some strangely named column ('ÃƒÆ’_OBJECT'), that can not be written in the standard encoding. What do you get from `names(deermig.sp)`, or `names(dermisg.sp@data)` ?

Comment: `> names(deermig.sp) [1] "Ãƒ_OBJECT" "CllrSrN"   "DtYrAnJ"   "UniquID"   "Species"   "Captrlc"   "CaptrAr"   "CollrID"   "date"     [10] "geometry" `

Comment: `> names(deermig.sp@data)
Error: trying to get slot "data" from an object (class "sf") that is not an S4 object ` Still can't figure out why it's doing this. Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: When I used the script in the past the fields looked like this: `names(deermig.sp)
 [1] "ïOBJECT"  "CllrSrN"  "DtYrAnJ"  "UniquID"  "Species"  "Captrlc"  "CaptrAr"  "CollrID"  "date"     "geometry"`

Comment: I'd try modifying the name of the first column using, for example, names(deermig.sp)[1] <- "Af_OBJECT"

Comment: Thanks, that was actually the problem. For some reason, it was changing the field name for Object which was messing with the shapefile outcome.

Answer (score 10):

This error (*CPL_write_ogr*) seems to be related to the data type. I had the same issue today and I just solved it. Here is how - I found out that my object was not sf or sfc but a *geometrycollection*. One has to turn it back into a simple (multi-)polygon, then it works.

```
Simple feature collection with 1 feature and 4 fields
geometry type:  GEOMETRYCOLLECTION
dimension:      XY
bbox:           xmin: 486390.1 ymin: 6044675 xmax: 487045.9 ymax: 6045202
projected CRS:  WGS 84 / UTM zone 32N
```

Create a sf polygon by extracting it from the collection using:

```
mydata2 <- st_collection_extract(mydata, "POLYGON")
```

I was then able to save the new file properly, i.e...

```
st_write(mydata2, "mydata2.shp")
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether it will help, but can You try `st_write(deermig.sp, paste(out.dir, migtimes$newUid[i], "_", i ,".shp", sep=""), layer_options = "ENCODING=UTF-8")`?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried that and get this error: "Error: Could not guess driver for..." I'm totally stumped.

Comment: Ah sorry, by `...`, I meant the arguments You already had, sorry my bad! That is:`st_write(deermig.sp, paste(out.dir, migtimes$newUid[i], "_", i ,".shp", sep=""), layer_options = "ENCODING=UTF-8")`. I will correct it above.

Comment: Okay thanks for the clarification. Still getting this error:"Error in CPL_write_ogr(obj, dsn, layer, driver, as.character(dataset_options),  : 
  Write error"

Comment: Okay, damn... unfortunately, I only got this idea as I can't replicate the problem. Good luck, hope there is a solution!

Answer (score 0):

If the first time worked, maybe using `overwrite=TRUE` in options:

```
st_write(deermig.sp, paste(out.dir, migtimes$newUid[i], 
 "_", i ,".shp", sep=""), overwrite=T)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I get this error when using the overwrite:" Error in st_write.sf(deermig.sp, paste(out.dir, migtimes$newUid[i], "_",  : 
  unrecognized argument(s) overwrite"

Comment: The correct argument for this function is "delete_layer" not "overwrite", just substitute and it should work!